# Jenkins — два билда на одной ноде

Tags: jenkins

Возможно ли в Jenkins делать два билда одного одинакового проекта на одной ноде одновременно?

Возник вопрос исходя из того, что если запустить два билда одновременно, то один из них обязательно завершится с ошибкой.

Comment: какая возникла ошибка?

Comment: Если вы в них используете одни и те же ресурсы или в один путь складываете файлы, то ошибка вполне возможна. Расскажите, какая ошибка была?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins умеет обрабатывать такую ситуацию. Он для следующего экземпляра делает workspase как workspase@<номер экземпляра> (могу ошибаться в последовательности). Скорее всего ошибка возникает в шагах сборки. Нужны детали.